# When i insert the data using PyQt5 and UI, i got the error "Python has stopped working"

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, pyqt5

I use Python3.5,PYcharm,PyQt5,Wampserver and for connection i used MySQLdb for connection

I use Mysql.connector also

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QMessageBox,QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot
import sys
import MySQLdb as mdb

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "PyQt5 Window"
        self.top =100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500
        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):   
         self.lineedit1 = QLineEdit(self)self.lineedit1.setPlaceholderText('please enter your name')
            self.lineedit1.setGeometry(200,100,200,30)
            self.lineedit2 = QLineEdit(self)
            self.lineedit2.setPlaceholderText('please enter your email')
            self.lineedit2.setGeometry(200, 150, 200, 30)
            self.lineedit3 = QLineEdit(self)
            self.lineedit3.setPlaceholderText('please enter your phone') self.lineedit3.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 30)
            self.button=QPushButton('Insert Data',self)
            self.button.setGeometry(200,250,100,20)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.InsertData)
            self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
            self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
            self.show()

    def InsertData(self):
         con = mdb.connect('localhost','root','','pyqt')
         with con:
             cur=con.curssor()
             cur.execute("INSERT INTO data(name,email,phone)"
    "VALUES('%s','%s','%s')"(''.join(self.lineedit1.text()),''.join(self.lineedit2.text()),''.join(self.lineedit3.text()))                                            
             QMessageBox.about(self, 'connection', 'successfully connect')
             self.close()  

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: change `''.join(self.xxxx.text())` to `self.xxxx.text()`